# How do I go about achieving a 2d simulation of a sports match like Big Win Soccer/Basketball/Hockey etc does?

Tags: android, mobile, 2d, game-engine, simulation

Basically, I'm referring to a bunch of apps made by Hothead games studio, but the app itself is Big Win Soccer.

Screenshots of the app itself for a bit of understanding of the app..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSOzx.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CRaK.jpg

I can already calculate the stats of the games I'm simulating, for example;

- Number of shots on target/ off target
- Possession stats
- Number of goals
- Number of red/yellow cards
- Number of Fouls
- At what time each incident occurs, i.e. Foul & yellow card at 5'

But what I want to achieve is a 2d animation of the game that has been calculated. Basically use the stats to simulate a soccer match, that doesn't jump from one place to another.

It's easy enough to call a shooting animation whenever a goal is scored, but how do I make sure its flowing smoothly, i.e. the build up animation towards the goal, without it jumping from one animation scene to another.

Does anyone know how the logic behind that would work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, the simulation works by flipping over bits in memory from 0 to 1 and others back from 1 to 0. Based on the broadness of the question that seems like a reasonably accurate answer.

Comment: Very funny, it's difficult to explain but basically I want to be able to have a simulation of a soccer game that you can view in a birds eye view way like a few different soccer management games. I can calculate all of the stats, possession, goals, number of cards, fouls etc etc.. but with that data, how do you go about matching the stats up with the 2d match simulation itself. I.e, if an incident happens at 5' of the 90' match, say a goal.. how do I show the animation of the build up to the goal without just showing an animation of the goal itself, without jumping from 1 place to another

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I've reworded the question, if you could take another look I'd appreciate it. I apologize for the "vagueness" of that question.

Comment: It's still too broad. Essentially you want to know how to program an AI that performs animations and ultimately scores goals (or performs fouls). So the simplest solution would be to create one set of animation for a given situation, say midfielder kicks to offensive player who shoots and either scores or doesn't. You then play back each set of animations for each data entry you have (ie shot on goal vs goal scored). Randomize so you don't see 10 shot attempts and goals followed by 7 bookings.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D So do you reckon you'd have a set of different animations for the same action in every square on a grid and play the one that fits the timeline?

Comment: No grids, no. Just an animation which includes the movement of the entire playfield and all players for that particular situation (ie scoring a goal). You can add multiple animations for each, ie three different ways to score a goal. If your data says "score a goal" you play back one of the "score goal" animations and wait till its finished (or perhaps skipped by the user). This is how most 2D soccer managers do it, at least the older ones I remember. Of course you'll quickly see each of the ~10 variations of (not) scoring a goal etc. That's the downside.